# How to use STL Map with Struct?

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, stl

I wanna use STL Map with struct

I wanna find process name,PPID,PID,path with CreateToolhelp32Snapshot and save these things in this struct ProcessMap.

and after 0.5 secs, search those Process things again and compare struct for update.
Please Help me..

for example

```
typedef struct ProcessMap
{
    boolean Survival;
    CString FileName;
    int PPID;
    int PID;
    CString Path;
};
```

Is it right that use like this?
(The Key is PID)

```
map<ProcessMap, int>Pmap;

map<ProcessMap, int>::iterator it;
```

Thanks for read this.

Comment: if PID is the key, then i think map should be declared like this:                       map<int, ProcessMap> Pmap

Comment: than how can I push things into "Pmap"? for example) Survival = FALSE; FileName = (LPCTSTR)pe32.szExeFile; PPID = pe32.th32ParentProcessID; PID = pe32.th32ProcessID;
etc.... how can I fill? mymap.insert(PPID,FALSE,pe32.szExefile... ) like this?